# Object.assign can`t find declared variable

Tags: javascript, object

I feel like my problem is really easy to solve, but I cannot see it. I have simple thing to do, get `myObject` from another function and store this in my storage object. For this task I created `storageHandler` function. Everything works fine, but `Object.assign` is not reaching my `'ID'` that I declared in this function earlier. This is weird because I don't know how to tell my function that `'ID'` is variable, not a string. I just expect it to be `{1212313: {...}}` but instead it gives me `{ID: {...}}`.
Someone have any idea how to fix it?

```
  let  storage = {}

  const myObject =  {       
  ID: '1223424525221',
  name: 'Thomas',
  mail: 'example@example.com'
  }


  storageHandler = data => {
    const {ID} = data;
    
    Object.assign(storage, {ID: data})
    console.log(storage)
  }

  storageHandler(myObject)
```

Comment: If you are setting a single property, why not just `storage[ID] = data`?  Seems like you are over complicating this.

Comment: @Taplar yea, I just didn`t know about this way, thank you for telling it.

Comment: Also a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in javascript this

```
a = { b: 1 };
```

is the same as

```
a = { "b": 1 };
```

You should change the Object.assign() for something like this

```
storage[ID] = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using string as a property name. Use computed property name like `[ID]` instead of `ID`. Computed property allows you to have an expression be computed as a property name on an object.

```js
let storage = {};

const myObject = {
  ID: '1223424525221',
  name: 'Thomas',
  mail: 'example@example.com',
};

storageHandler = (data) => {
  const { ID } = data;

  Object.assign(storage, { [ID]: data });
  console.log(storage);
};

storageHandler(myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the value of `ID` as key of object using `[]`.

```js
Object.assign(storage, {[ID]: data})
```